# It seems schema.org/Review is not recognized by Google Search anymore or I made a mistake

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I have received a message a couple of days ago that Google Search Engine has a problem identifying my ObjectType 'ItemReviewed'.

I am a collaborator on a moviesite and implement schema.org to my reviews.

---

```
    <div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <span itemprop="reviewBody">

    <span itemprop="itemreviewed">Title of the movie</span>

    <IMG>itemprop="image"</IMG>


    <img border="0" src="https://example.com/wp-content/img/30star.png" alt="rating" />
    <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "0"/>Rating: <span itemprop="ratingValue">3</span> / <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span></div>
    Review by <span itemprop="author">Selina</span> op <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2020-02-13">13 februari 2020<p></div>
```

---

Can anybody help me. It worked fine for years up until a few days ago.

NOTE: I know google has recently changed the markup for businesses so the rating is not something self-serving, but this a movieblog and the ratings are rating the movie not the website. Should I use another markup?

We are talking about genuine, independent, and unpaid editorial reviews

Answer (score 0):

Google recently started to report on reviews.

In your case you have marked up itemprop="review" outside the scope of an item. Which is invalid unless you did not share all the code?

You've also marked up itemreviewed. It should be itemReviewed with capital R. You should not place the review in another item and use itemReviewed at the same time. They are different ways to do the same thing.

Your itemReviewed is just some text. This is interpreted as it being a 'Thing'. Google only supports reviewing a very restricted list of types, where a basic Thing is not included:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet

Movie is on the list, which I suspect is what you are reviewing. So you need to mark up your Movie and either place the review inside that with the property review, or place the Movie inside your review with the property itemReveiwed.

Answer (score 0):

does this code looks 'ok' to you or should I add something else, cause there are a lot properties and I would like to have a minimum amount of them, cause I will have to make changes to up to 1000 movie reviews.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CriticReview">
     <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">

<span itemprop="name">movie title</span>
<span itemprop="director">Alfred Hitchcock</span>
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2020-02-19">19 februari 2020</meta>

<a href="https://example.com/wp-content/img/img_2004_blu-ray.jpg"><img itemprop="image" src="https://example.com/wp-content/img/img_2004_blu-ray.2.jpg"/></a>

     </div>

<span itemprop="author">name of the author of the review</span>

<div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
<meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "0"/>
Rating: <span itemprop="ratingValue">1</span> / <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>

</div>
```

Second question, should I use meta tags or span tags, or doesn't it matter?